# Show that the number $2^{2^{2n+1}}+2^{2^{2n}}+1$ is not prime.

Tags: prime-numbers, square-numbers, power-towers

**question**

Show that the number $2^{2^{2n+1}}+2^{2^{2n}}+1$ is not prime, for any nonzero natural number $n$.

**my idea**

$ 2^{2^{2n+1}}+2^{2^{2n}}+1 = 2^{2^{2n}}*5+1 $ i did this by giving common factor.

From here we can easily observe that the last digit of thiz equation is $1$ and also this equation has the form $k^2*5+1$. I tried using some modular arithmetic but i obteined nothing. I got stuck here and i dont knkw what to do forward.

Hope one of you can help me! Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to look a little closer at that "common factor" step of yours. Do it very carefully, one tiny step at a time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2^{2^{2n+1}} = 2^{[2 \cdot (2^{2n})]} = (2^{2^{2n}})^2$

So you end up with $X^2+X+1$ where $X=2^{2^{2n}}$. I guess you can start from there.
It's easy to see that, if $X \mod 3 = 1$, then $3 | X^2+X+1$, so I guess you need to move in that direction.

Comment: Can you tell me if i contiuned your idea corect?

So $X^2$, because is a square can only be 0 or 1 modulo 3, but $x^2$ is only divisible with $2^k$ => $x^2$ is congruent 1 modulo 3

$x={2^{2^n}} ^2$ ao it means is also a perfect square so it can only be 0 or 1 modulo 3 butis only divisible with $2^k$ => x is congruent 1 modulo 3

From here we get that the whole equation is divisible with 3 so it mrans its not prime

Comment: I gave the assist, and you scored the goal. Congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

Both $2^{2n+1}$ and $2^{2n}$ are even, thus $2^{2^{2n+1}}\equiv (-1)^{2^{2n+1}}\equiv 1$ and $2^{2^{2n}}\equiv (-1)^{2^{2n}}\equiv 1$ modulo 3. It follows that $2^{2^{2n+1}}+2^{2^{2n}}+1$ is divisible by 3, and so it is not prime.

Comment: @Beleth: This isn't the argument, the argument is that $x$ is even $\Rightarrow$ $2^x \equiv 1 \mod 3$

Comment: My bad (I couldn't read properly...), I delete my comment !